# Is spinOnce needed?

Tags: ros, spinonce, spinning, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have ROS node that has an infinite loop that has other things running, do I need to use spin or spinOnce?  The other items have specific timing such as 100 and 50 Hz but the subscriber I have does not need to but so specific. Can I call the subscriber some how in the loop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65735/is-spinonce-needed?/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2013-06-22

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*For single-threaded nodes:*

If you have an infinite loop of your own that does some processing, use `spinOnce()` somewhere in the loop. This allows ROS to process the callbacks for queued messages - if you don't include it, your callbacks will never be called and none of your messages will be published.

If all your calculations are performed in callbacks and you don't need an infinite loop for your custom processing, just use `spin()` which continuously pumps for callbacks.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5